# When IIFE return a value, where does the value exist?

Tags: javascript, iife

When I tried the example on [babel Symbol](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/) in the example there was no return, so I added it cause I thought it should be(I am not sure if I am right).

It logged in my console `MyClass` is not defined.

If IIFE returns a Class, why it said `MyClass` is not defined?

```
(function() {

  var key = Symbol("key");

  function MyClass(privateData) {
    this[key] = privateData;
  }

  MyClass.prototype = {
    doStuff: function() {
    }
  };
  return MyClass //this is no return for the original example
})();

var c = new MyClass("hello")
c["key"]
```

Answer (score 4):

As with any other function call, the value goes to the left hand side of the function.

```
var return_value_of_x = x();
```

or

```
var return_value_of_iife = (function () { return 1; })();
```

Since you have nothing on the LHS of your IIFE, the value is discarded.

In your example `MyClass` is a variable declared within the IIFE. It doesn't exist outside that function. You could create another variable with the same name in the wider scope:

```
var MyClass = (function () { …
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store the value somewhat like this if your IIFE is returning a value.

```
let returnedValue = (function(){console.log('return'); return 2;})();
```