# JavaScript assign value to variable only if certain condition is met (without repetition)

Tags: javascript

say I'm defining a JavaScript variable like this:

```
var sheetsToWorkWith =
    (
        allSheets.length > 0 ?
        allSheets
        .filter(x =>
            x.cssRules && [].slice.call(x.cssRules).filter(y =>
                Object.keys(data).includes(y.selectorText)
            ).length > 0
        ) :
        []
    ) ||
    (() => {
        var style = head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
        style.type = "text/css";
        return style.sheet;
    })(),
```

Basically what this variable assignment (did/) does is check if an existing stylesheet exists, and if not, then assigns it to a new one. What I want it to do now is set it to a LIST of stylesheets, with any of them containing a selectorText that matches an element in a pre-defined array, however it seems to do that I would need two variables: I want to set it equal to the first value (to the right / top of the || operator) only if the length of the result is greater than 0.

Comment: The expression after `||` will never be evaluated because the first expression always returns an array. Empty arrays are not falsy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first value from the array only if `allSheets.length > 0` is true then just  reference the first element by index `[0]`.

```
var sheetsToWorkWith = (
  allSheets.length > 0 ?
    allSheets.filter(x => 
      x.cssRules && [].slice.call(x.cssRules).filter(y => 
        Object.keys(data).includes(y.selectorText)))[0] // index the first element
  :
    []
  )
||
...
```

Note that `Array.prototype.filter` always returns an array, and accessing an empty array by index results in `undefined` ensuring your first expression returns the `else` part of the ternary (`[]`).

**Edit**

OP wanted the `else` part of ternary to be evaluated, therefore, what one can do is:

```
var sheetsToWorkWith = (
  allSheets.length > 0 ?
    allSheets.filter(x => 
      x.cssRules && [].slice.call(x.cssRules).filter(y => 
        Object.keys(data).includes(y.selectorText)))[0] // index the first element
  :
    (() => {
        var style = head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
        style.type = "text/css";
        return style.sheet;
    })()
  )
```

Comment: I want the entire array, but only if it's length is greater than 0, and if it is 0, then move on to the ||

Comment: Like I said in the comments, the expression after `||` will never be evaluated. I'll update my answer to address this.

Comment: The expression after `||` will not return the actual sheet, even with `return style.sheet` there, because it is scoped differently, [read about IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185406/when-iife-return-a-value-where-does-the-value-exist). You'd need to assign that to something. `var myResult = (() => { ... return style.sheet; })()` and now `myResult` will have your sheet.